# Size of a custom view is not in pixels in methods onDraw() and onSizeChanged() . Is it possible set dimension in pixels?

Tags: android, canvas, android-custom-view

I have simple custom view but it size is not in pixels in methods `onDraw()` and `onSizeChanged()`.

In my case width is 1920 pixels, but width of canvas is 1440 ( k=0.75 ).
This is Ok if you want to draw a vector graphics, but I do not want rescale bitmap. For example a bitmap has size 64*64 pixels, if you will use `canvas.drawBitmap( bitmap, 0,0,64,64, null);` then bitmap will blur as real size on the screen will more then 64 pixels.

Is it possible to set resolution for canvas of a custom view in pixels?

Comment: I think you're confused.  onDraw doesn't pass in a size at all.  You can get the size of a view by calling getWidth and getHeight, and those values are absolutely in pixels.  I think you need to tell us why you think the width is 1920 and how you're seeing it as 1440.  Because somewhere you're getting some piece of data incorrectly.

Comment: Also, if you have a 1920 width pixel bitmap and expect to draw it without scaling on all devices-  that's not going to happen.  Devices have different dpi and different physical widths.  Scaling is just something you deal with in Android.  There's techniques to prevent you from scaling too much, but a single bitmap won't fit all device widths perfectly.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I use simple Log, and mean canvas.getWidth() and canvas.getHeight(). But in method onSizeChanged I get the same. So there is no mistake. 1920 - width of screen shot. If you try to draw a rectangle 500*500 you will get ~684*684 in pixels.

Comment: The size returned by those functions are pixels.  I'm not sure where you're getting 1920 from, or getting this screen shot, but all measurements to the graphical system in Android are in pixels.  So once again, you're measuring something incorrectly.  If you want help, you need to explain exactly what you're doing to get all these numbers, because we can't guess how they were formulated.  Its far more likely that your method of getting a screenshot is scaling than anything else.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I spend 2 hours and just uninstall/install the app and it was 1920, so it was unknown bug. Thank you.